# Run web application as program in Windows and MacOS

Tags: html, web-applications, executable, desktop-application

I'm looking for a way to create an executable program where I can use HTML as UI instead of native elements like in a Windows Form application, or a Java form application.

One requirement is that I also need to be able to create text files locally. These text files will be created when a button is pressed somewhere in the HTML UI.

Another thing is that it should be able to run on both Windows and MacOS.

So I'm really looking for something like PhoneGap/Cordova. But then for a desktop OS.

Anyone any idea if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Chromiumembedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) might be what your'e looking for.

You could also have a look at [Titanium.](http://www.tidesdk.org/)